# Sorting of date table column with EU date format

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I'm trying to produce a data table that contains a sortable column with dates in eu-format (dd.mm.yyyy) in shiny. I tried to use the date-eu.js plugin, but it does not work. Here's an example code:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
     tags$head(tags$script(src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/sorting/date-eu.js")),
     dataTableOutput("tab")
  ), 
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tab <- renderDataTable({ 
      data.frame(x = 1:6, y = 1:6, date = format(Sys.Date() - c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75), '%d.%m.%Y'))
    }, options = list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sType = "date-eu", aTargets = list(2)))))
  }
))
```

Unfortunately, the sorting does not work properly. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to set the column classes on the data frame, or use `stringsAsFactors`

Comment: It does not seem to matter whether the `date` column is of type `character` or `factor`.